# Should we start closing resource requests for algorithm implementations, can we have a close reason added?

Tags: discussion

This question was recently bumped up because someone posted a "me too" non-answer: [Looking for this supervised Clustering (SCEC/SRIDHCR) algorithm in R](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/15506/looking-for-this-supervised-clustering-scec-sridhcr-algorithm-in-r)

We have others like it, I don't want to single it out for special attention, but focus on it as an example. It clearly has not been well received, and the answers are not directly useful or upvoted.

Many other Stack Exchange sites close questions that simply ask for off-site resources.

I'd like to vote to close this question as off-topic, but I don't feel confident yet that the site consensus is that it *is* off topic (as opposed to just a low-quality question). The list of standard off-topic reasons does not support me closing, and we also do have some successful resource request questions, for more generic resources such as "deep learning libraries for Python" or identifying courses and learning materials.

The subject matter of the question clearly *is* related to Data Science, so IMO it needs a clearly supported reason to be considered off-topic. None of the current set of standard close reasons are a good fit.

So, three main questions for discussion:

- Should the linked question be off-topic - why/why not?
- Are any resource search questions on-topic for Data Science site, if so what is difference between acceptable and unacceptable ones?
- Should we have a close reason to cover requests for resources that the site does not want to handle, and how should it be worded?

Comment: IMO StackEchange needs a section to ask for resources and questions usually flagged as opinion based.